# Dectecting side collisions using rectangles in Java

Tags: java, awt, collision, java-2d

This is my first week of Java, and I'm making a game that involves rectangles bouncing off of each other. The rx and ry are the coordinates of the rectangles, and the velRX and velRY are their x and y velocity. I'm trying to make it so that the rectangles bounce off of each other (reversed y velocity) but continue with the same x velocity if they collide on the top or bottom, and vice versa for the left and right sides. However, I don't know how to detect which side the rectangles collide on. Could I have some help?
relevant code

```
//Checking for collision between Nemesis and Cop
    public boolean checkCollisionOther() {
        Rectangle r1 = rect1.getBoundsNemesis();
        Rectangle r2 = rect2.getBoundsCop();

        if (r1.intersects(r2)){
            collision = true;
            rect1.velRY = -rect1.velRY;
            rect1.velRX = -rect1.velRX;
            rect2.velRY = -rect2.velRY;
            rect2.velRX = -rect2.velRX;
        }
        else
            collision = false;
        return collision;       
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: this may be of use: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25818/how-to-implement-a-2d-collision-detection-for-android/40235#40235

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create bounding rectangles for each of the edges of your two game rectangles.  Since there are 4 edges to a rectangle, you have 4 bounding rectangles for a rectangle.

You have 4 bounding rectangles for the cop and 4 bounding rectangles for the nemesis.  This means you have to do 16 `intersects` tests in a double `for` loop.

When one of the `intersects` tests returns true, you can determine which edge of your cop rectangle and which edge of your nemesis rectangle had the collision.

Here's some code to illustrate how to create bounding rectangles.  You can make them wider than 3 pixels if you want.

```
public List<BoundingRectangle> createBoundingRectangles(Rectangle r) {
    List<BoundingRectangle> list = new ArrayList<BoundingRectangle>();
    int brWidth = 3;

    // Create left rectangle
    Rectangle left = new Rectangle(r.x, r.y, brWidth, r.height);
    list.add(new BoundingRectangle(left, "left"));

    // Create top rectangle
    Rectangle top = new Rectangle(r.x, r.y, r.width, brWidth);
    list.add(new BoundingRectangle(top, "top"));

    // Create right rectangle
    Rectangle right = new Rectangle(r.x + r.width - brWidth, r.y, brWidth,
            r.height);
    list.add(new BoundingRectangle(right, "right"));

    // Create bottom rectangle
    Rectangle bottom = new Rectangle(r.x, r.y + r.height - brWidth,
            r.width, brWidth);
    list.add(new BoundingRectangle(bottom, "bottom"));

    return list;
}

public class BoundingRectangle {
    private Rectangle rectangle;
    private String position;

    public BoundingRectangle(Rectangle rectangle, String position) {
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Rectangle getRectangle() {
        return rectangle;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public boolean intersects(Rectangle r) {
        return rectangle.intersects(r);
    }

}
```